# Getting the output of Terraform's Provisioner "remote-exec" with SSH type connection

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way I can run a command with Terraform's `remote-exec` provisioner (via `ssh` type connection) and get the output?

Alternatively, if there is no way of doing that, what other options do I have to run a command on the machine that Terraform is creating and get the output?

Comment: You could potentially use the external data source with a bit of hackery. Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly you're trying to achieve and why you need Terraform to know the result of what you ran on the target machine?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR This is part of a complex system that must decide whether there are migrations in the newly deployed code. If there are, old machines must be stopped first, a backup of the RDS must be created, a new machine with a "We'll be back shortly" msg is created, etc...

Comment: That sounds way too complicated for Terraform to be doing directly. Surely you're running this via some wrapper scripts or an orchestrator such as Jenkins?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Yes, I am. But still, I need to, somehow, run the "are_there_any_missing_migrations()" function inside the machine that terraform is launching.

Comment: What's stopping you running that via SSH in the wrapper script?

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, I think you're right. It would be better if I return the IP of the newly created machine and then run whatever I need inside my wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the 'local-exec' provisioner to run a script already on the server, or could copy the script to the server using the 'file' provisioner. you could then capture the output by piping into a file locally and then read it using the 'local_file' resource.